# MQTTClient Listener disconnects randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, mqtt

I have an MQTT listener written in c#.
The program is running in Azure and
for some reason after a period of time, it gets disonnected with an exception:
"The operation has timed out." or
"Exception of type 'MQTTnet.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationTimedOutException' was thrown."

On production, the listener must always be online so on disconnect event i'm reconnecting, but it happens randomly, it can get disconnected 4 times a day and sometimes it can stay online without disconnect for a  few days.

question is, why is it happening? the device that it listens to is sending a timestamp request every few minutes, but it should be very fast and shouldn't cause a timeout.

Here is the code:

```
private static IMqttClient _client;
private static IMqttClientOptions _options;

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
        //create subscriber client
        var factory = new MqttFactory();
        _client = factory.CreateMqttClient();
        //configure options
        _options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
            .WithClientId("ListenerClient")
            .WithTcpServer(Utility.brokerIp, Utility.brokerPort).WithCredentials(Utility.brokerUser, Utility.brokerPassword)
            .WithCleanSession()
            .Build();

        //Handlers
        _client.UseConnectedHandler(e =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully with MQTT Brokers Topic.");
            WriteToLog("***Connected To MQTT Listener.***");
            //Subscribe to topics******************
            
        });
        _client.UseDisconnectedHandler(e =>
        {
            WriteToLog("***DisConnected From MQTT Listener.***");
            WriteToLog(e.Exception.Message);
            _client.ConnectAsync(_options).Wait();
            return;

        });
        _client.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(async e =>
        {
           //manage messages
        });

        //Connect
        _client.ConnectAsync(_options).Wait();
        Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)).Wait();
        _client.DisconnectAsync().Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue at one time, I believe the queue you are trying to connect to has very intermittent traffic. And then whatever service, or server you have hosting the queue it self, is setup to hibernate the queue when no traffic hits the queue for some predetermined period of time.

When you then try to use the queue, the "timeout" happens because the queue can't wake up from hibernation quick enough for you to get a processed message through.

if the queue is Azure hosted, try to get Azure support to confirm this is the case, if you are on premise hosting, try to verify your own configuration is set this way, and reduce the "wait" period to something deliberately small like 30 seconds, and verify that a hibernated queue, causes a time-out.